# Hover function for accordion

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide

Thus far you guys have been wildly helpful with me getting this little ditty working just so. I have one further request:

This markup:

```
          <div id="themes">
          <h2>Research Themes</h2>
            <ul>
              <li class="tier_1"><a class="enviro" href="">Learn about our approach to the <strong>environment</strong></a>
                <ul class="tier_2 hide">
                  <li><a href=""><em>How we are tying this all together</em></a></li> 
                  <li><a href="off.html"><strong>Project:</strong> Solor Powered Biofactories</a></li> 
                  <li><a href=""><strong>Project:</strong> Cleaning Water with Nature</a></li>
                  <li><a href=""><strong>Project:</strong> Higher Efficiency Solar Technology</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="tier_1"><a class="health" href="">Learn about our approach to <strong>human health</strong></a>
                <ul class="tier_2 hide">
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero uno goes here</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero dos goes here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero tres goes here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="tier_1"><a class="defense" href="">Learn about our approach to <strong>national defense</strong></a>
                <ul class="tier_2 hide">
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero uno goes here</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero dos goes here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Project name numero tres goes here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- // end themes -->
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".tier_1 > a").hover(function() {
    var currentList = jQuery(this).parents('li').find('.tier_2');
    $(currentList).slideToggle();
    jQuery(this).parents('ul').find('.tier_2').not(currentList).slideUp();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Create this nifty 'themes' slider you can see working on the right column of this page: http://clients.pixelbleed.net/biodesign/

I have two problems with it...The hover retracts the slideUp/down when you hit one of the links under a tier_2 ul. I'd like it to remain slideout as someone hovers the nested li's. So the slide should only happen on hover for the tier_1 elements. Also I would like, on hover to add an "active" class to the a element on the tier_1 links. So [a class="enviro"..] would, on hover, become [a class="enviro active"]. This is then removed when one of the other tier_1 items is hovered. This way the pretty color icon can stay visible while someone looks at the nested elements.

Not even sure all that is possible with hover, but I figured if anyone would know a way it would be here.

Comment: What's wrong with using a pre-made accordion? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: @Justin - that's a good idea, though there can be times when you don't want to retheme your entire site to fit with jQuery UI and simply want similar behavior.

Comment: Using jQueryUI doesn't force you to use their theme's.  You can style the accordion accordingly (no pun intended).  If you don't like that, then you can just use a plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to have a `mouseout` handler on your themes DIV, which slides up all of the nested uls and a `mouseover` handler for each `tier_1` anchor that closes the other nested uls and slides open it's nested ul.  That way you only get the panels closing when you switch to a different panel or out of the thems div entirely.  You could omit the `mouseout` if you wanted the last selection when in the themes DIV to remain selected.

```
$(function(){
  $('div.themes').mouseout(function() {
       $('.tier_2:visible').slideUp();
       $(this).find('a.active').removeClass('active');
  });
  $(".tier_1 > a").mouseover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('div').find('a.active').not($this).removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    var currentList = $this.parents('li').find('.tier_2'); 
    $(currentList).not(':visible').slideDown(); 
    $('.tier_2:visible').not(currentList).slideUp(); 
    return false; 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Your explanation sounds exactly like what I am looking for, but this snippet (only tried it locally), has the same problem as the one I was working with--doesn't leave tier_2 nested items visible when I go to hover them. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Banderdash -- Needed to replace the slideToggle with slideDown, though @Justin's comment about using an accordion has merit.